# How to access SQL Configuration Manager

Tags: login, database, visual-studio, sql, c#

Upon checking the programs installed on my machine, it says that I have SQL Server 2014 installed. However I can't access the Configuration Manager in the "All apps" of the start menu to make a database. I'm trying to create a simple login form in Visual Studio but upon creating a database it says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 50: - local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.)

Do I understand it right or am I just doing something wrong? Help with this error please?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the configuration manager in your start menu, you can try this:

1. Run mmc
2. Go to file->add/remove snap-in...
3. Find the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" snap-in
4. Click add then Ok.

Here's a screenshot for your reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** is not the same as the **SQL Server Management Studio**.  SQL Server Configuration Manager is for configuring the protocols and services related to all your SQL Server instances.  But to create and manage your databases, you want SQL Server Management Studio.

You many not see SQL Server Management Studio in your programs if it wasn't installed along with SQL Server.  Even though your computer shows SQL Server is installed, remember there are several modules and you may not have selected to install the Management Studio.  Actually, Microsoft offers smaller downloads that don't include the studio.  Either way, it is very likely that you didn't install the Management studio.

To install SQL Server Management Studio, either:

1. Re-Run your SQL Server installation file and select the check box for the Management Studio option if it is available.
2. OR, download the SQL Server Management Studio from Microsoft at this link: 
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42299  
   On that page you will see the red Download button.  Click that and then scroll to the bottom and select the SQLServerManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe file. 
    It should look like this: [image: Screen Shot of Download page]